# SharePoint Online reports error file is locked for exclusive use (by check-out user) using CSOM

Tags: c#, csom

I am working on a Word Add-In that exports a PDF file from a Word document to a SPO list and assigns ContentType and some SharePoint meta data to the new PDF file.
The list is configured with:

- Version Control with major and minor is active
- check-out for files is required

Exporting and adding the file to the PSO list works. But when the Add-In tries to assign a new content type SPO raises an exception "file is locked for exclusive use by . But this user executes the Add-In.

The same method works, if check-out for files is not required on the list.

```
public void FileAssignContentType(string relativeFullName, string listTitle, string contentTypeName)
{
    try
    {
        // connect to list
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List list = this.web.GetListByUrl(listTitle);
        this.clientContext.Load(list);
        this.clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        // get content type
        ContentType newCT = list.GetContentTypeByName(contentTypeName);
        this.clientContext.Load(newCT, x => x.Id);
        this.clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        // assign content type to file
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = this.getFile(relativeFullName);
        this.clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        ListItem item = list.GetItemByUniqueId(file.UniqueId);
        this.clientContext.Load(item);
        this.clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        item["ContentTypeId"] = newCT.Id;
        item.Update();
        this.clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); // -> raises exception
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
```